# How to set breakpoint in Chrome for when flash video is loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, flash, flv

In the Chrome debugger's 'Network' tab, the 'Other' sub-tab shows a .flv Flash file being played. I'm trying to figure out exactly where/how that .flv URL is being generated, but I've looked through the JS for the site and can't figure out where it comes from.

Is there a way to set a breakpoint for when that .flv file starts getting streamed/played so that I can figure out how it's URL is being put constructed?

The request headers for the flv file in the Chrome debugger show `X-Requested-With:ShockwaveFlash/24.0.0.194`. So the request comes from Flash rather than from a JS file I think.

Or any other ways to figure it out?

Comment: _"Is there a way so that I can figure out how it's URL is being constructed?"_ Where's the link? No clues in source code?

Comment: The request headers for the flv file show `X-Requested-With:ShockwaveFlash/24.0.0.194`, show it's come from Flash rather than from a JS file I think.

Comment: Either the embedded SWF (Flash) app has specific code to construct the url (then method is unknowable) or else the app is reading the url from somewhere like a JSON or XML text file. It could also construct by reading the text within an HTML / JS file. Third possibility is that PHP is involved in generating a link. So check the `Network` tab for such things (xml, json,php files which you open in new tab to read). No _flv_ found when you word-search the source of html or JS?...  It's all maybe's without a testable link. PS: No load breakpoints / pausing in Chrome.

Comment: Please put your last comment in an answer, I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the embedded SWF (Flash) app has specific code to construct the url (then method is unknowable) or else the app is reading the url from somewhere like a JSON or XML text file.

It could also construct by reading the text within an HTML / JS file. Third possibility is that PHP is involved in generating a link. So check the `Network` tab for such things (xml, json,php files which you open in a "new tab" to read).

Was there no `flv` found when you word-search the source of html or JS?... 
If all else fails then provide a testable link.

PS: To answer your Question : There's no loader breakpoints / load pausing in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

On Network tab you have multiple columns. One of them it's called `Initiator`. If' is missing, right click on any column and a dropdown with all columns available will appear. Check `Initiator` column.

That column should tell you what you need to find out.

Comment: Initiator says `Other`. Unfortunately no further information is provided there. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot where it says 'Other'. I haven't meet this case untill now. I always encountered something like ClassName.MethodName @ script._namejs:line_number